# dojo mobile - tab bar beneath home bar

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.mobile

Intended layout:

```
------------------------
| (back)  (title)      |
------------------------
| (tab1) (tab2) (tab3) |
------------------------
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
------------------------
```

The intent here is to have a `dojox.mobile.Heading` right at the top, a `dojox.mobile.TabBar` beneath it, and the rest of the screen taken up by the content, as depicted above.

When the user navigates between the various screens within the app, the `Heading` must change (title and back button), but the `TabBar` does NOT change. On some screens however, the TabBar is hidden.

Now I am trying to figure out how to do this w.r.t. to `dojox.mobile.View`s. I see two potential ways of achieving this:

1. Have both the `Heading` and the `TabBar` in a root `View`, which contains several sub `View`s which the `TabBar` navigates between. Rewrite the contents of the `Heading`, triggered by navigation events on the `TabBar`.
2. Have several `View`s which contain a `Heading`, and an empty `div`. Rewrite the empty `div`'s contents with the contents of a `div` somewhere else in the page, not contained within any `View`, which contains a `Heading`.

Which of the above methods is the preferred/ standard way of accomplishing this in DOJO mobile?

Are there yet more ways in which this can be accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: @mschr : Could you please elaborate on how you would do this with a code example?

Answer (score 1):

You can also just put the heading and the tab bar at the toplevel (i.e. as direct children of your body), both with a fixed="top" attribute. They will be stacked one below the other. Then just put your different views after that (still as children of the body).

Below is a sample that shows this solution (no Back button in the heading, but you get the idea...). Save this in an HTML file in the dojox/mobile/tests directory of your Dojo install to run it.  This is for Dojo 1.7.2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>

<title>Heading + TabBar</title>

<link href="../themes/iphone/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../themes/iphone/TabBar.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblAlwaysHideAddressBar: true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "dojo/ready",
        "dojo/_base/array",
        "dojox/mobile/parser",
        "dojox/mobile",
        "dojox/mobile/compat",
        "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView",
        "dojox/mobile/TabBar"
    ], function(ready, array){
        ready(function(){
            var f = function(view, moveTo, dir, transition, context, method){
                var child = array.filter(this.getChildren(), function(w){
                    return w.moveTo === view.id; })[0];
                if(child){ 
                    child.select();
                    heading.set("label", child.get("label"));
                }
            };
            tabBar.subscribe("/dojox/mobile/afterTransitionIn", f);
            tabBar.subscribe("/dojox/mobile/startView", f);
        })
    });
</script>

<style>
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="visibility:hidden;">
<h1 jsId="heading" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" data-dojo-props='fixed:"top"'>Heading</h1>
<ul jsId="tabBar" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBar" data-dojo-props='fixed:"top"' style="border-bottom:none;">
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" data-dojo-props='icon1:"images/tab-icon-16.png", icon2:"images/tab-icon-16h.png", moveTo:"featured"'>Featured</li>
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" data-dojo-props='icon1:"images/tab-icon-15.png", icon2:"images/tab-icon-15h.png", moveTo:"categ"'>Categories</li>
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" data-dojo-props='icon1:"images/tab-icon-10.png", icon2:"images/tab-icon-10h.png", moveTo:"top25"'>Top 25</li>
</ul>

<div id="featured" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView">
    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"categ"'>
            Categories
        </li>
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"top25", transitionDir:-1'>
            Top 25
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="categ" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView">
    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"top25"'>
            Top 25
        </li>
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"featured", transitionDir:-1'>
            Featured
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="top25" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView">
    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"featured"'>
            Featured
        </li>
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"categ", transitionDir:-1'>
            Categories
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input - investigating this now!